# Mocking out multiple method calls using Jasmine

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm trying to write a test in JavaScript, the method I'm testing makes 2 method calls (model.expandChildren() and view.update();)

```
// inside 'app' / 'RV.graph'
var expandChildren = function(){
    return model.expandChildren().then(function(r) {
      view.update(r);
    });
};
```

I've tried to use Jasmine specs to write the test to spyOn both the view and model functions, but it appears you can only have 1 spy in a given test.  It seems I'm missing something big here and that there should be a way to mock out multiple methods calls using spies since my function needs to make both of these calls.

I want my spec to be able to run the way it is below, but it currently only passes the first test (the first spy runs as expected), the second test fails because Jasmine is trying to run the actual function, not the spied function:

```
var model = GRAPH.model;
var view = GRAPH.view;
var app = RV.graph;

describe('#expandChildren', function() {

    beforeEach(function() {
        // first spy, all good
        spyOn(model, 'expandChildren').and.callFake(function() {
          return new Promise(function(resolve) {
            resolve(testResponse);
          });
        });
        // second spy doesn't work because Jasmine only allows 1
        spyOn(view, 'update');
        app.expandChildren();
    });

    // passing test
    it('calls model.expandChildren', function() {
        expect(model.expandChildren).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

    // failing test that runs the REAL view.update method
    it('calls view.update', function() {
        expect(view.update).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

Is there a way to do this with Jasmine?

Answer (score 1):

Remember that you are working with asynchronous calls. The first call is synchronous, so it is recorded, but the second one only happens later. Give yourself some control over when things happen. I commonly use a pattern like this:

```
describe('#expandChildren', function() {
    var resolver;

    it('calls model.expandChildren', function(done) {
        spyOn(model, 'expandChildren').and.callFake(function() {
          return new Promise(function(resolve) {
            resolver = resolve;
          });
        });
        spyOn(view, 'update');

        app.expandChildren();

        expect(model.expandChildren).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(view.update).not.toHaveBeenCalled();

        resolver();
        done();

        expect(view.update).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

This way, the spec will only be run after the promise has been resolved and `done()` has been called.

Comment: Resolving is definitely another issue here, but even with the `done()` my 2nd test is still failing. I may be misunderstanding, but I was under the impression that only one spy can be used per describe block, even if you have multiple spies in a test suite.

Comment: There is no restriction in the number of spies you can create. Anyway, resolving a promise synchronuously on creation might be to early. I have never tried that pattern, but always resolved by hand. This way you additionally test your async code _is_ only executed later. See edited answer.